# Easiest way to manage clones of third-party repositories?

Tags: git

Currently I am working on a project that requires me to use several open-source libraries. Now, I'd like to be able to do the following:

- Be able to pull upstream changes from the third-party repository.
- Be able to modify these libraries if needed.
- Have all libraries in one repository instead of having to create a new repository for each fork.

I've considered using Git submodules but that wouldn't allow me to make changes to the libraries.

I've considered forking each library and adding those forks as submodule (but this is not ideal considering it would require me to make a repository for each fork).

I've considered downloading all repositories into one which would allow me to modify them at will and have them in one repository, but this wouldn't allow me to be able to pull upstream changes from the third-party repository.

Is there any way that I can have all three points fulfilled instead of having to pick one of these options?

Comment: `Git submodules but that wouldn't allow me` ? How it wouldn't? When you want to make changes, just do them inside the submodule and normal `git add`+`git commit`. There is also `git subtree`, but `git submodules` is much cleaner, especially with open source repos that you need to publish.

Comment: @KamilCuk A bit of clarification: it would allow me to change the code, but it wouldn't allow me to commit it considering that the repository is from a third-party and thus I do not have contributor rights to it.

Comment: I'm still puzzling over "but this is not ideal considering it would require me to make a repository for each fork". Sounds ideal to me. A fork _is_ a repository and it costs nothing to make except maybe five seconds of time. So why is it bad?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Git, there is no other or more elegant way.

**option 1: git submodules**

checks criteria 1 & 2, but not 3. Assuming third-party is outside your control, there is no way you may enforce criteria 3.

**option 2: git fork a superproject of third-party submodules**

checks all criteria. Criterion 3 is matched since you may can fetch from third-party submodules remotes, commit locally/push locally (i.e. push to your superproject of submodules inside your company/project domain).

**option 3: put all files in a big repo from third party, create a repo of this melting pot**

doesn't check option 1.

In the end you already have your answer, and I would not go outside this scope, otherwise the question would go towards being very opinion-based.